# Delete row in a DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datagridview, row

I tried to loop through my `dataGridView1` and remove rows which don't satisfy the condition as following:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (!(Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[7].Value) - DateTime.Today).Days <= 0)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row); //error: Uncommitted new row cannot be deleted.
    }
}
```

But I got this error:

> Uncommitted new row cannot be deleted.

I can manage if the code also VB.NET.

Comment: It would be better to remove the records from the data source than to try to remove them from the datagridview.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `foreach` in this case, the looped collection may be modified and leads to unpredicted result, sometimes throws exception like collection was modified (encountered mainly in `LINQ`), use `for` instead:

```
 for(int i = dataGridView1.RowCount-1; i >= 0; i--){
   var row = dataGridView1.Rows[i];
   if (!row.IsNewRow&&!(Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[7].Value) - DateTime.Today).Days <= 0){
      dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);
   }
 }
```

Note that we have to loop from the largest index to 0.

Comment: I encountered @King King's warning: looped collection may be modified when using foreach. Great solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
 if (!(row.Cells.OfType<DataGridViewCell>().All(c=>c.Value == null))
  {
   if (!(Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[7].Value) - DateTime.Today).Days <= 0)
   {
     dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with putting following condition:

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {

                  if(!row.IsNewRow)
                  {
                     if (!(Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[7].Value) - DateTime.Today).Days <= 0)
                     {
                       dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);
                     }
                  }

                }
```

Comment: I have tried your code, but not all rows were deleted even they satisfy the condition.