# How do i remove a row that is not equal to "0"? I tried this but it removes only 2 or 3 rows

Tags: datagridviewrow

// the lup that goes through every row
                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                    {

```
                   if (dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["Payment"].Value.ToString()!="0")
              {


                        dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);

                       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but if you are removing rows while you cycle through them, you may be skipping rows.  If you delete a row and then increment your index, you may skip the next row.  Would you try cycling backwards through the table like this link suggests?  [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20014863/delete-row-in-a-datagridview-c-sharp)